# Inno Script to find out which IDE of Visual Studio is installed.?

Tags: inno-setup

How do we find the Visual Studio Installed using Inno Script.e VS 2005/2008/2010/2012.?

And how to run a particular batch file for different Vs.?

Let us suppose i want to run Install_Help_Vs2010.bat if Vs installed is 2010, Install_Help_Vs2012.bat if Vs installed is 2010 and so on.??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the registry keys.

Read the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 -> InstallDir` key.
(There may be Wow64 redirection on 64bit Windows - take care!)

The result looks like

> e:\Visual Studio 2010\Common7\IDE\

which is path to Visual Studio.

**10.0** in registry key is a variable which is dependent of Visul Studio version:

for Visual Studio 2005 - 8.0

2008 - 9.0

2010 - 10.0

2012 - 11.0

2013 - 12.0

To launch the .bat file simply use **Exec()** function: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec

I cannot post whole script example as correct usage depends on the way how you handle your .bat files.

Are .bats already included in your setup or they are created dynamically (e.g. path to VS is read from registry and written into .bat file)?

And where are they stored? In some temporary folder or in VS folder or in application folder?

But basically you need to do simple if() conditions or case() switch and create/execute appropriate .bat file.